# Join fetch: "query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list"

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a following code:

```
public class ValueDAO  implements BusinessObject<Long> {

    private Long id;
    private String code;
    private ClassDAO classDAO ;
        ....
}

public List<String> getCodesByCodeClass(Long classId) {
    String select = "select distinct val.code from ValueDAO val left " +
        "join fetch val.classDAO ";
    String where = "where val.classDAO.id = ? order by val.code";

    return getHibernateTemplate().find(select + where, classId);
}
```

It raises an exception:

```
 org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list
```

In the result I wan to get only codes.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`join fetch val.classDAO.b` means "when fetching `val`, also fetch the `classDAO` linked to the `val`". But your query doesn't fetch `val`. It fetches `val.code` only. So the fetch makes no sense. Just remove it, and everything will be fine:

```
select distinct val.code from ValueDAO val 
left join val.classDAO classDAO
where classDAO.id = ? 
order by val.code
```

Some notes, though:

- doing a left join and then adding a retriction like `classDAO.id = ?` means that the join is in fact an inner join (since classDAO can't be null and have the given ID at the same time)
- naming your entities XxxDAO is very confusing. DAOs and entities are not the same thing at all.

Given the above, the query can be rewritten as

```
select distinct val.code from ValueDAO val 
where val.classDAO.id = ? 
order by val.code
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation on this. I had the same issue and your answer just cleared the problem with my query. In my case I was using something like this:
"
select a
  from x
    join x.a as a
join fetch x.a.lazyA
join fetch x.a.lazyB;
"
Just changed to:
"
select a
  from x
    join x.a as a
join fetch a.lazyA
join fetch a.lazyB;
"
and it worked!