# Hibernate HQL eager load collection in embedded object

Tags: hibernate, hql, eager-loading

I have a class that has embedded object

```
public class A {
   @Embedded
   private B b;

   // getter setter
}
```

Inside B class, I have a collection e.g.

```
@Embeddable
public class B {
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="A_ID")
    List<C> cList;
}
```

and class C

```
@Entity
public class C {
    // not important
}
```

Now I want to query A object using HQL and also retrieve the C list eagerly.  I have tried

```
select a from A a join fetch a.b.c c
```

but I get this error `Join fetch: “query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list”`

I read this [Join fetch: "query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496945/join-fetch-query-specified-join-fetching-but-the-owner-of-the-fetched-associa) and it seems that it is because my collection is stored inside an embedded object.

Of course I can do for loop and utilize `Hibernate.initialize` but the performance will drop when more data is being fetched.

Is it possible to do this in HQL at one shot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to eager load the embedded collection using HQL. I believe you need to modify you HQL a bit.

I have tested with following entities:

**NOTE:** Added **Multi** to your entity names as I already have classes with same name `A`, `B` and `C` in my work space and added `@Id` annotation along with `toString` method etc.

```
@Entity
class MultiA {
    public MultiA() {}

    public MultiA(List<MultiC> cList) {
        this.b.cList = cList;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int id;
    @Embedded

    public MultiB b = new MultiB();
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MultiA [id=" + id + ", b=" + b + "]";
    }

}

@Embeddable
class MultiB {
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="A_ID")
    List<MultiC> cList = new ArrayList<MultiC>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MultiB [cList=" + cList + "]";
    }

}

@Entity
class MultiC {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int id;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MultiC [id=" + id + "]";
    }
}
```

And finally the HQL used is:

```
session1.createQuery("select distinct a from MultiA a join fetch a.b.cList").list()
```

This results in firing the below single SQL using join :

```
Hibernate: select distinct multia0_.id as id1_0_0_, clist1_.id as id1_1_1_, clist1_.A_ID as A_ID2_1_0__, clist1_.id as id1_1_0__ from MultiA multia0_ inner join MultiC clist1_ on multia0_.id=clist1_.A_ID
```

and gives the following output that returns 2 entities of `MultiA` along with `MutliC` populated.

```
[MultiA [id=1, b=MultiB [cList=[MultiC [id=1], MultiC [id=2], MultiC [id=3]]]], 
MultiA [id=2, b=MultiB [cList=[MultiC [id=6], MultiC [id=4], MultiC [id=5]]]]]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for! Just to summarize, I dont need to specify the alias for join fetch.

Comment: In addition, I think "left outer join" will be useful here since using "outer join" will only fetch MultiA object with MultiC collection

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the alias for `c` in the HQL, like this:

```
select a from A a join fetch a.b.c
```

The alias is only needed if you need to use it directly in a `where` or `select` clause, and also when you need to do some joins of attributes of `c` class.