# JPQL JOIN on Foreign Key causes SQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, jpql

I have two entities `Order` and `Customer`. `Order` has a `@ManyToOne` relationship with `Customer`. However, when I declare the following JPQL query, I get an `SQLSyntaxErrorException` because the generated SQL is missing the `ON` condition.

JPQL:

```
SELECT o.id,
       o.incrementId,
       o.externalId,
       o.state,
       o.status,
       o.couponCode,
       o.totalDiscount,
       o.total,
       o.originChannel,
       o.branchOffice,
       o.createdAt,
       o.updatedAt,
       c.fullName
FROM Order o
JOIN FETCH Customer c;
```

Generated SQL:

```sql
select order0_.id             as col_0_0_,
       order0_.increment_id   as col_1_0_,
       order0_.external_id    as col_2_0_,
       order0_.state          as col_3_0_,
       order0_.status         as col_4_0_,
       order0_.coupon_code    as col_5_0_,
       order0_.total_discount as col_6_0_,
       order0_.total          as col_7_0_,
       order0_.origin_channel as col_8_0_,
       order0_.branch_office  as col_9_0_,
       order0_.created_at     as col_10_0_,
       order0_.updated_at     as col_11_0_,
       customer1_.full_name   as col_12_0_
from orders order0_
inner join customers customer1_ on;
```

As you can see, it's missing the condition `on`. I find that strange, because these are my entities:

**Order** (Irrelevant properties omitted for brevity)

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {
    
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private int id;
    
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "id", table = "orders")
   private Customer customer;
    
   public Customer getCustomer() {
       return customer;
   }
}
```

**Customer** (Irrelevant properties omitted for brevity)

*My use case doesn't require that I have a `List<Order>` in the `Customer` entity* (I tried adding it and that doesn't solve the problem anyway.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer {
    
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private int id;
    
   public int getId() {
      return id;
   }
    
   public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
   }
}
```

The relationship between these two entities is correct because it works as expected when it comes to inserting, updating and retrieving by normal means. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the following jpql:

```
select o from Order o join o.customer
```

See also the [documantation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join).

Comment: Thank you, this worked, but had to remove the `fetch` keyword because I'm not fetching the entire `Order` entity and Hibernate was complaining. Related answer about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12497188/10587134